# managing .adf's in QGIS or SAGA?

Tags: raster

I have a few .adf's that I aquired from a fellow using ArcGIS (as I understand, this format is a specific ArcGIS format). 
I can open it up in qgis but their relative geographic position is off, seems the information is lost and all layers "upper left corner" are stuck at 0,0. 
The cell sizes should be 2,-2 and 50-50, but all cell sizes for all rasters are set to 1,-1.
Is there a way I can manage these files in QGIS without losing this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have ESRI arcinfo Grids. The two Grid types are ascii or binary. I do not know if QGIS reads the coordinate system of an ESRI Grid. To verify that your raster is intact you can use Gdalinfo to list the GRID coordinate system. Also, you might install one of these free viewers, TatukGIS Viewer or ArcGIS Explorer Desktop to view your raster. If you need to convert your Grids to another format, gdal_translate is a great command line conversion tool.